# list the difference and overlap between two plain data set

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, text-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/linux-tools-to-treat-files-as-sets-and-perform-set-operations-on-them)

I have two data sets, A and B. The format for each data set is one number per line. For instance,

```
12345
23456
67891
2345900
12345
```

Some of the data in A are not included in data set B.  How to list all of these data in A, and how to list all of those data shared by A and B. How can I do that using Linux/UNIX commands?

Comment: [Possible duplicate: "Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343/11539)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `comm` command.

If you lists are in files `listA` and `listB`:

```
comm listA listB
```

By default, comm will return 3 columns.  Items only in listA, items only in listB, and items common to both lists.

You can suppress individual columns, with a `-1`, `-2`, or `-3` arg.

Comment: The answer assumes listA and listB are already sorted. A more general solution: `comm <(sort listA) <(sort listB)`

Comment: Very simple solution. Is the `comm` command deployed in all linux distro?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the unique items that exist in A but not in B:

```
cat A|perl -ne '$z=$_;chomp($z);$y=`grep $z B`;if ($y== "") {print "\n$z";}'|sort -u
```

This will give you the list of common items in both A and B:

```
cat A |xargs -i grep {} B|sort -u
```