# Subtracting Binary files

Tags: files, cat

I have 2 Binary Files  `FileA` and `FileC`

Its is such that `FileC = FileA + FileB` using the `cat` utility

How do I subtract  `FileA`  from  `FileC`  to get  `FileB` ?

*PS: I am using Ubuntu Oneiric*

Comment: they are binary files, so it can get hard. If it is a text file, it is possible to use little bit of grep or perl stuff to get back fileB.

Comment: As @Nikhil said, it would be possible with a regular file to [treat them as sets and do set operations on them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/linux-tools-to-treat-files-as-sets-and-perform-set-operations-on-them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuling you have `stat` on your plateform to get the size of `FileA`, you could do something like:

```
dd if=./FileC of=./FileB bs=1 skip=$(stat -c %s ./FileA)
```

which should work on any type of file.

Comment: This works assuming that content of FileA was put or concatenated into FileC before FileB. But works for me, because its me who will put FileA before FileB into FileC. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to know where to cut. For binary files, this generally means knowing the size of `FileA` or `FileB`.

You can find the size of `FileA` with `ls -l`. If you need to write a portable script, you can extract the size with `ls -lgo FileA | awk '{print $3; exit}'` (or, for non-POSIX-compliant versions of `ls` that don't have the `-g` and `-o` options, `ls -l FileA | awk '{print $5; exit}'`). On non-embedded Linux, a simpler way to obtain the size is `stat -c %s FileA`.

Once you have the size, you can use `tail` to extract the second part of the file:

```
tail -c +$((sizeA + 1)) <FileC
```

If you want to break a file into equal chunks, use the `split` command.