# Symmetric Difference Pipe?

Tags: text-processing, coreutils, file-comparison

I have a command that produces a lists of strings followed by newlines, `a`, and a file containing a list of strings followed by newlines, `b.txt`. I need a command that calculates the symmetric difference of the output of `a` and contents of `b.txt`. Ideally this command should operate in a pipeline, as `a` is potentially very slow.

Venn diagram if you like those (Credits to Wikipedia):

[image: Symmetric Difference Operation]

For those more example oriented:

`a` outputs

```
apple
car
```

`b.txt`

```
banana
car
dog
```

Then the result should be

```
apple
banana
dog
```

Comment: Okay, I read more manpages, and I've figured out a solution if I can redirect `a` to a file: `sort {a,b}.txt | uniq -u`. `a` is unfortunately slow (~one second per line, >100 lines), so if anyone has a pipe-based solution, I'll accept that.

Comment: http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html#sets

Comment: See also [Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/linux-tools-to-treat-files-as-sets-and-perform-set-operations-on-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort solution may be a bit faster if you sort the files separately, then
use `comm` to find the non-common lines:

```
sort a.txt -o a.txt
sort b.txt -o b.txt
comm -3 a.txt b.txt | sed 's/^\t//'
```

Alternatively, if one of your data files is not too large, you can read it all into an associative array then compare the other file line by line. Eg with awk:

```
awk '
ARGIND==1 { item[$0] = 1; next }
ARGIND==2 { if(!item[$0])print; else item[$0] = 2 }
END   { for(i in item)if(item[i]==1)print i }
' a.txt b.txt
```

In the above `ARGIND` counts the files arguments. 
The first line saves file 1 lines in array `item`. The next line sees if the current line from file 2 is in this array. If not it is printed, else we note that this item was seen in both files. Finally, we print the items that were not seen in both files.

If one of your files is much smaller than the other, it is best to put it first in the args so the item array stays small:

```
if [ $(wc -l <a.txt) -lt $(wc -l <b.txt) ]
then args="a.txt b.txt"
else args="b.txt a.txt"
fi
awk '
ARGIND==1 { item[$0] = 1; next }
ARGIND==2 { if(!item[$0])print; else item[$0] = 2 }
END   { for(i in item)if(item[i]==1)print i }
' $args
```

Comment: Would the awk solution work if `a` were piped in?

Comment: You can always simply replace one of the filenames by `-` and then awk will read stdin for that file: eg: `cat a.txt | awk '...' b.txt -` however, it is only when you get to the end of both files that you can show which items in b.txt did not appear in a.txt.

Comment: how could it possibly be faster? a only writes a line per second - processing time is not the bottle neck.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) to treat the output of a command as a file.

```
comm -3 <(a | sort) <(sort b.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

A good tool to see differences is `diff`, you just need to play a little bit with its non-trivial options to format the output properly:

```
diff --unchanged-group-format= --new-group-format="%>" a b.txt
```

---

If `a` is not a file by a pipe then you should use `-` instead:

```
echo 'apple
car' | diff --unchanged-group-format= --new-group-format='%>' - b.txt
```

Output:

```
apple
banana
dog
```

---

Or if you don't care the context where a line appeared in the file:

```
echo 'apple
car' | sort | diff --unchanged-group-format= --new-group-format='%>' - <(sort b.txt)
```