# Pairwise combinations of filenames

Tags: bash

If I have n files in a directory, for example;

```
a
b
c
```

How do I get pairwise combinations of these files (non-directional) to pass to a function?

The expected output is

```
a-b
a-c
b-c
```

so that it can be passed to a function like

```
fn -file1 a -file2 b
fn -file1 a -file2 c
...
```

---

This is what I am trying out now.

```
for i in *.txt
 do
  for j in *.txt
   do
    if [ "$i" != "$j" ]
     then
      echo "Pairs $i and $j"
     fi
   done
 done
```

Output

```
Pairs a.txt and b.txt
Pairs a.txt and c.txt
Pairs b.txt and a.txt
Pairs b.txt and c.txt
Pairs c.txt and a.txt
Pairs c.txt and b.txt
```

I still have duplicates (a-b is same as b-a) and I am thinking perhaps there is a better way to do this.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343/117549

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the file names in an array and run through it manually with two loops.

You get each pairing only once if if *j < i* where *i* and *j* are the indexes used in the outer and the inner loop, respectively.

```
$ touch a b c d
$ f=(*)
$ for ((i = 0; i < ${#f[@]}; i++)); do 
      for ((j = i + 1; j < ${#f[@]}; j++)); do 
          echo "${f[i]} - ${f[j]}"; 
      done;
  done 
a - b
a - c
a - d
b - c
b - d
c - d
```

Comment: Note that it is better to use `printf` rather than `echo`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo

Comment: @cryptarch, to be in line with the question, the content of the loop should be a call to `fn`, instead of `echo` or `printf`. `echo` works fine as an example here, though.

Comment: Sure, it's not broken, you already got my +1 ;)

Answer (score 5):

You're very close in your script, but you want to remove duplicates; i.e a-b is considered a duplicate of b-a.

We can use an inequality to handle this; only display the filename if the first file comes before the second file alphabetically.  This will ensure only one of each matches.

```
for i in *.txt
do
  for j in *.txt
  do
    if [ "$i" \< "$j" ]
    then
     echo "Pairs $i and $j"
    fi
  done
done
```

This gives the output

```
Pairs a.txt and b.txt
Pairs a.txt and c.txt
Pairs b.txt and c.txt
```

This isn't an efficient algorithm (it's O(n^2)) but may be good enough for your needs.

Comment: This will take more than twice as long as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490657/305714 because you are checking each pair twice rather than restricting the loop to avoid redundancy

Comment: Yes, but without knowing the cost of `fn` it's hard to know if this overhead is significant or not.  Taking 0.2s instead of 0.1s doesn't mean anything if every call to `fn` takes 1 second.  Sometimes the naive algorithms are just fine ;-)  In this case I just fixed the original code, rather than providing a more optimised alternative, because I considered it a better "teaching" solution.

Answer (score 1):

With `join` trick for filenames without whitespace(s):

Sample list of files:

```
$ ls *.json | head -4
1.json
2.json
comp.json
conf.json
```

---

```
$ join -j9999 -o1.1,2.1 <(ls *.json | head -4) <(ls *.json | head -4) | awk '$1 != $2'
1.json 2.json
1.json comp.json
1.json conf.json
2.json 1.json
2.json comp.json
2.json conf.json
comp.json 1.json
comp.json 2.json
comp.json conf.json
conf.json 1.json
conf.json 2.json
conf.json comp.json
```

---

- `-j` option points to a common field position to join on; but `-j9999` will provoke mixed joining resembling *cartesian* product.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in *.txt ; do
  for j in *.txt ; do
    if [ "$i" '<' "$j" ] ; then
      echo "Pairs $i and $j"
    fi
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use perl's `Alogithm::Combinatorics` module to avoid having to devise the algorithm yourself.

```
perl -MAlgorithm::Combinatorics=combinations -e '
  if ((@files = <*.txt>) >= 2) {
    for (combinations(\@files, 2)) {
      system "cmd", "-file1", $_->[0], "-file2", $_->[1];
    }
  } else {
    die "Not enough txt files in the current working directory\n";
  }'
```

See `perldoc Algorithm::Combinatorics` for details and other things that module can do.