# one line shell to output all combinations of letters in a word

Tags: shell, awk, sed, perl

I have a word like:

```
fath
```

output all combinations of letters in a word like:

```
f
fa
fat
fath
ft
fth
fh
```

Comment: Those aren't all combinations, of course. Do you want this exact output or do you want all possible combinations? Also, what do you have so far? Which part of this is giving you trouble?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11667/117549

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916316/1745001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Here is a one line `awk` solution:

`echo f a t h | awk '{for(i=0;i<2^NF;i++) { for(j=0;j<NF;j++) {if(and(i,(2^j))) printf "%s",$(j+1)} print ""}}'`

Output

```
f
a
fa
t
ft
at
fat
h
fh
ah
fah
th
fth
ath
fath
```

(modified version of this power set implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40966428/awk-power-set-implementation)

Comment: Where is `hat`? Is the output inclomplete?

Comment: The command persists the order of the letters

Comment: @Panki `ath` is present and the OP asked for combinations, not permutations.

Comment: why is `echo f a t h` not `echo fath`

Comment: the letters needs to be space separated  for the awk script. You can add spaces to "fath" by piping it through `sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'`

Answer (score 1):

bash:

```bsh
combos () {
    local word=$1
    local len=${#word}
    local first=${word:0:1}
    echo "$first"
    for ((i=1; i < len; i++ )); do
        for ((j=1; i+j <= len; j++ )); do
            echo "$first${word:i:j}"
        done
    done
}
```

then

```
$ combos fath
f
fa
fat
fath
ft
fth
fh
```

Comment: That's missing `f` and combinations that don't include `f`, e.g. `at`.

Comment: That's missing f

Comment: @JohnChen, fixed.