# Remove Common lines in a file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two files **fileA** & **fileB**

fileA has lot of IPs & fileB has less IPs. How can we do

> fileA - fileB = fileC (File without common IPs)

**fileA**

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

**fileB**

```
4.4.4.4
1.1.1.1
```

**fileC**

```
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
5.5.5.5
```

I got lot of options on google but couldn't get anything relevant

Comment: You should have included in your example an IP in fileB that doesn't exist in fileA so we could see if that should appear in the output or not. Everyones making different assumptions...

Comment: Do you want the **intersection** or actually the **complement** ? Please read the descriptions (definitions) in https://catonmat.net/set-operations-in-unix-shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do `fileA - fileB`, you can use awk (this will not get you IP only in `fileB`):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' fileB fileA
```

`NR` refers to the total record number and `FNR` refers to the record number (typically the line number) in the current file. So if a line exist in the first file, it won't be displayed from the second.

---

If you need to get rid of duplicate line in fileA use :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}!a[$0]++' fileB fileA
```

Answer (score 8):

The `comm` tool may be useful here, particularly if you don't care that the results are sorted in alphanumerical order:

```
comm -23 <( sort -u fileA ) <( sort -u fileB ) >fileC
```

See `man sort` and `man comm` for reference details of their use.

Comment: That is assuming that you want the complement of fileA (sutract fileB from FileA, `fileA - fileB`).  If what is wanted is the *Symmetric Difference* (elements that are in set1 or in set2 but not both) you could use `sort <(sort -u fileA) <(sort -u fileB) | uniq -u` (or `comm -3`).

Comment: @QuartzCristal yes. I read the question as wanting to use FileB to eliminate IP addresses from FileA.

Comment: Yes ! I agree, that is my perception as well. But then, I read a sentence like *(File without common IPs)* and I left wondering if what is meant is to eliminate repeated IPs anywhere they appear. Well, nevermind, there is nothing that you should do with your answer, not until the OP could clarify what is he meaning to say.

Answer (score 3):

The question can be interpreted in a couple of different ways.

I will assume that each line is unique in the file it occurs in.

- Assuming you want to remove the entries from `fileA` that are also found in `fileB`.

  This removes the IP addresses found in `fileB` from the ones in `fileA`:

  ```bash
  grep -v -Fx -f fileB fileA >fileC
  ```

  The options used with `grep` here ensure that the patterns (lines read from `fileB` using `-f`) are treated as strings rather than as regular expressions (`-F`), and that we are matching whole lines rather than substrings (`-x`).  We also invert the sense of the match with `-v` to output all lines from `fileA` that does not match any of the lines in `fileB`.
- Assuming you want to get all entries that are unique to `fileA` *or* that are unique to `fileB`:

  The following outputs the lines that are not duplicated across the files.  It uses `-u` with `uniq`, which is a non-standard but commonly available option used for outputting lines that are not duplicated over subsequent lines.

  ```bash
  sort fileA fileB | uniq -u >fileC
  ```

Comment: `sort fileA fileB fileB | uniq -u` Need to duplicate the common IPs. Edit the answer pls.

Comment: @K-att- That is correct, but only if fileB contains values that doesn't exist in fileA. That is not what the OP supplied as examples, but yes `sort fileA fileB fileB | uniq -u` is the correct solution.

Comment: @K-att- My intention was to list the entries that were not repeated between the files. If I use `fileB` twice, then I would get no entry from that file. If `fileB` contains an entry that is not in `fileA`, then I was assuming that the user wanted to see it.  This is what I meant by there being different interpretations of the problem.

Comment: fileA - fileB = fileC (File without common IPs)

Comment: @K-att- Exactly. If you use `fileB` twice in the call to `sort`, then you will get _no_ elements from `fileB`, even if the file contains elements that are not common to both files.

Comment: @Kusalananda You are interpreting the question as getting the intersection of both files and printing what is not common to both of them. But the procedure you decided to use (with `sort`) require that there are not repeated values in `fileA`. If you add a value `6.6.6.6` twice in `fileA` it will not be printed on the output.

Comment: @Kusalananda An alternative interpretation of `fileA-fileB` is that of subtraction (removal of values in `fileB` from `fileA`). That is what you did with the `grep` example and the `sort` command is **not** an equivalent.

Comment: @Kusalananda The description in https://catonmat.net/set-operations-in-unix-shell might be of help. And the solutions already exist in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/linux-tools-to-treat-files-as-sets-and-perform-set-operations-on-them

Comment: @QuartzCristal Yes, I assume that each file contains lines that are unique within that file.  This is an assumption that is already part of my answer. I also say that there are different ways of interpreting the question, then I give two different answers, together with two different interpretation.  This is also part of the text already.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But plain rejection is not better than trying to include some/any of the helpful points: (1) you can comment (note, write, say, include) that your assumption of that each file is a set (no repeated lines) could be enforced with `<(sort -u file A)`. (2) That the equivalent to your grep solution is `sort fileA fileB fileB | uniq -u`  with the `sort` command. (3) That a seemingly cleaner equivalent to `sort fileA FileB | uniq -u` which enforce assumptions is `comm -13 <(sort -u fileB) <(sort -u fileA)`. (4) And that there is another existing Unix answer that might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

If preservation of order is not important, you can first remove duplicates in first file and concatenate the output with second file twice (for removing anything unique to it) and print only non-duplicate lines with `uniq -u`.

```
sort -u fileA | cat - fileB fileB | sort | uniq -u
```